# SwiftUI: how to change NavigationView.toolbar background color

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

Any idea on how to apply a specific background color to the bottom toolbar?

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ....
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button(action: { model.selectTab(tab: "ITEM1") }, label: { Text("ITEM1") })
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button(action: { model.selectTab(tab: "ITEM2") }, label: { Text("ITEM2") })
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button(action: { model.selectTab(tab: "ITEM3") }, label: { Text("ITEM3") })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually you can just do `.background(Color.blue)`

Comment: @aheze unfortunately if I chain that to the toolbar, the background color doesn't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `UIToolbar` appearance. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    
    init() {
        UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Item")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: { }, label: {Text("ITEM1")})
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: { }, label: {Text("ITEM2")})
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: { }, label: {Text("ITEM3")})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me...

Comment: Copied that exact code.  It does not work.

Comment: On iOS 16 not working.

Comment: On iOS 17 this works only for the "standard appearance" not for the "scroll edge appearance" when there is content scrolling behind the toolbar.

Comment: I used this and it was also not working for me, except when I opened the screen a second time, it worked :-/

Answer (score 17):

**iOS 16 Onwards**

[image]

> Note: use .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
> The preferred visibility of the background of the bar.

Detail tutorial here - https://janeshswift.com/ios/swiftui/how-to-change-navigationview-colour-in-swiftui/

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Dashboard")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Text("Cool Title")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbarBackground(.red, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For .toolbar not working.

Comment: Hey @Ramis what you are trying ? may be i can help with that ?

Comment: This example showcase for .navigationBar (it is top bar). But it is not working when I try to use for .toolbar (bottom bar).

Comment: Hmm i guess `UITabBar.appearance().` is only way as of now.

Comment: With appearance not working as well.

Comment: You must use `Color.red` for setting the toolbar, not just `.red`

Comment: You must put everything inside NavigationStack {} otherwise .toolbar will be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

The code below doesn't work for me:

```
init() {
    UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

This code works:

```
init() {
  let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
  coloredAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
  coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = .systemRed
  coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
  coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
  
  UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
  UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
  UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
  
  UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
}
```

Taken from [Kristaps Grinbergs' blog](https://kristaps.me/blog/swiftui-navigationview/).

Comment: this worked not the selected answer

Comment: If you change UIToolbarAppearance to UIToolbarAppearance and remove the two TextAttributes lines, and maybe add compactScrollEdgeAppearance, this also works for the toolbar/bottomBar, as asked.

Answer (score 5):

iOS 16+

```
.toolbarBackground(
    .red,
    for: .navigationBar)
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
```

For more info:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/toolbarbackground(_:for:)

Comment: For .toolbar not working.

Comment: Are you using iOS 16? See the documentation above @Ramis

Comment: All of these comments are assuming the "normal" toolbars. .bottomBar doesn't seem to respond except to UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red. @Arturo, your suggestion works if you want to colour the navigation bar (the top) or the TabBar (the very bottom). But there is frustrating little control over the addition toolbar .bottomBar

Answer (score 0):

Here is bit hacky solution that avoids overriding `UIToolbar.appearance()` in the app. It can work for both Nav and Tab bar, or only for the one you choose (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72425447) for NavBar colouring only).

```
struct NavWithBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<100) {
                Text("Row \($0)")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 1) // note top 1 padding!
            .background(.red)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Text("ITEM1") })
                    Button(action: { }, label: { Text("ITEM2") })
                    Button(action: { }, label: { Text("ITEM3") })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("100 Rows")
        }
    }
}
```