# How to change background color of SwiftUI ToolBar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been trying to change the background color of the toolbar, and only the toolbar in SwiftUI with no success.

I have tried doing `UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red` and that was supposed to change the color but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI changing navigation bar background color for inline navigationBarTitleDisplayMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69196530/swiftui-changing-navigation-bar-background-color-for-inline-navigationbartitledi)

Comment: That adds the color to the navigation bar and the toolbar, but I want it to be only the toolbar, as it conflicts with another view in my app.