# SwiftUi - Weird navigation bar background color with Map in view

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

I have two tabs: one is a map inside a List and the other is a simple setting view.
This is the code for both:

**LocationView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Locations: View {
   var body: some View {
       NavigationStack{
           List{
               Section{
                   Map(){
                   }
              }
          }
        .navigationTitle("Locations")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
      }
  }
}
```

**SettingsView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
       List{
         Section{
          ....
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, problem is that I don't understand why with the same very code, the navigation (and tab bar) background looks like this:

[image]

while my SettingView navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have both with a solid gray color like the one in the SettingView.
Is it the map that makes the navigation and tab bar look like blurred?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I'd love both views to have the default color scheme for a List like this one:

[image]

Hiding the navigation bar won't do the trick. On scroll makes it disappear and it's not what I'm looking for.

Changing the background color works but makes me lose the "translucent" effect when the navbar collapses to inline mode.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is definitely the map. Removing it makes the two view look the same.
Looks like the map is stretching behind all the view in the background, even if it's inside a List -> Section

Comment: It's probably because the map is extending behind the navigation bar, so the bar adds a material background. You can hide it with ```.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)``` or set it to a solid color with somthing like ```.toolbarBackground(.gray, for: .navigationBar)```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI changing navigation bar background color for inline navigationBarTitleDisplayMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69196530/swiftui-changing-navigation-bar-background-color-for-inline-navigationbartitledi)

Comment: Technically, both are blurred. It's just that in Settings, there is only solid white color behind the bar, so you can't *see* the blurring effect.

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for. Please see the updated question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I tried exactly this except I wasn't filling the screen, still had the nav color change on me as well as the top scroll margin such that the map and nav bar touched, it's a bug for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS 17 Map view has a similar impact on tab bar appearance. I was able to force my own appearance by using Introspect to set the per item override property. Perhaps a similar approach would work for navigation bar as well.

```
.introspect(.tabView, on: .iOS(.v17), scope: .ancestor) { tabController in
    tabController.tabBar.selectedItem?.scrollEdgeAppearance = AppTheme.tabBarAppearance()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 0

> Looks like the map is stretching behind all the view in the background

So you can `clip` the map to prevent that like:

```
Map(){ }
    .clipped()
```

---

Method 1

You can make the navigation bar [have a custom color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72683139/5623035) like:

```
.toolbarBackground(.yellow, for: .navigationBar)
```

or just make it not-translucent somewhere in the app like:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
}

var body: some View { ,,, }
```

<sub>Method 1 is preferred over the method 2</sub>

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba but I'm trying to achieve a different thing: I'd like my LocationView to look exactly like my SettingView. They both have a List in them and I'd like the same look. Please see the updated question.

Comment: The problem is the Map as written in the UPDATE 2 part of my question.

Comment: the code you have provided for the `Locations` view, does not generate a view like the image you have posted on my machine. [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFJWH.png), so I don't really understand the specific issue

Comment: I have added another method due to your edits. Hope it works

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunately, ".clipped()" didn't work when used as the first modifier of the Map. I wonder if masking the entire map inside a Rectangle might help...

Comment: Can you share the code that generates [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Y5o.png)? So I can help you achieve the result you need.