# Is it possible to change the Navigation Bar Title colour in a SwiftUI view which includes a Map?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

Throughout my app, I have set the navigation bar title colour to a shade of blue with the use of an extension on `View`.

```
extension View {

    func navigationBarTitleTextColor(_ color: Color) -> some View {
        let uiColor = UIColor(color)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: uiColor]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: uiColor]
            
       return self
    }
}
```

In all views this looks fine, eg the Favourites tab below:

[image: Favourites tab with blue title]

But in a view that includes a `Map`, the colour of the title won't change. I have tried clipping the `Map`, but this does not work. All views are wrapped in a `NavigationStack` and I have narrowed down that the issue only occurs when using a `Map` inside the view.

[image: Stadiums tab with black title]

Code sample below:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct StadiumMapView: View {
    @State private var mapPosition = MapCameraPosition.automatic
    private var stadiums: [Stadium] = []
    @State private var path: [Stadium] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Map(position: $mapPosition) {
                    ForEach(stadiums) { stadium in
                        Annotation(stadium.name, coordinate: stadium.coordinate) {
                            NavigationLink(value: stadium) {
                                Image("logo_rounded")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    self.resetMapRegion()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Orange"))
                        .background(Color("Blue"))
                }
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding(10)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Stadium.self) { stadium in
                StadiumDetailView(stadium: stadium)
            }
            .toolbarBackground(Color("Yellow"))
            .navigationTitle("Stadiums")
            .navigationBarTitleTextColor(Color("Blue"))
        }
    }

    private func resetMapRegion() {
      mapPosition = MapCameraPosition.automatic
    }
}
```

Is it possible at all to change the navigation bar title's colour when using a `Map` and/or what is the cause of that it is not possible to change this when using a `Map` inside a view?

Comment: You don’t include any code that calls the method you’ve defined in the extension. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it’s easier to spot where any issue may lie.

Comment: you say the problem is when you include a `Map`, but you don't show that code, why? It seems to be important. Show the code you are using that is not working, including the Map, the NavigationStack and of course the View. Code that we can compile and run.

Comment: Added a code sample of the View including the Map

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color

Comment: I'm currently using the second answer for all my other views, only the one with the Map does not work for some reason. The first answer also has no effect on the view with the Map.

I did find this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634688/swiftui-weird-navigation-bar-background-color-with-map-in-view , but I did manage to fix the background colour, just not the text colour